# Flask-CORS returns random Access-Control-Allow-Origin if Origin request header is not provided

Tags: python, flask, cors, flask-cors

I want to enable CORS in my Flask application with a predefined set of allowed origins, as documented [here](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=['http://localhost:3000', 'https://app.my_domain.com'])
```

The problem is that if I don't specify the `Origin` header in my request to the server, an arbitrary value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header will be returned.

So for example, if my web application running on `https://app.my_domain.com` sends a `GET` request to the backend without specifying the `Origin` request header, the backend returns the following response header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`

This seems not correct to me. How is this mechanism intended to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Flask-Cors has an undocumented option called `always_send` which defaults to `True` (See [GitHub code](https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/blob/40acc8092332dfed4bb54d7a4f89a6d479466de7/flask_cors/core.py#L59) and a relevant [issue](https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/176)). What this option does is that it returns the origins even if the "Origin" header is not present.

To fix the issue you simply need to set the option to `False`:

```py
CORS(app, origins=['http://localhost:3000', 'https://app.my_domain.com'], always_send=False)
```